# Only while debugging: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: oracle, debugging, intellij-idea, jdbc

I have a Java application that accesses an Oracle 12 database.  When I run it outside the debugger, it runs fine.  If I try to debug it using IntelliJ's v2016.1.4 debugger, I get a `java.sql.SQLRecoverableException`, with the following stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:794) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:384) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:273) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:198) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:176) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at ...setDbConnection(OracleJmsQueue.java:537) [classes/:?]
    ...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:790) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.write(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:215) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:211) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.writeDataToSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:181) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.writeDataToSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:132) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForReading(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:96) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:534) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.receive(T4C8TTIdty.java:728) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.doRPC(T4C8TTIdty.java:639) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1544) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    ... 12 more
```

The interesting thing is that this only happens while debugging.  I can start the Java process outside the debugger, with remote debugging enabled using JPDA, and everything runs fine.  If I then attach a remote IntelliJ debugger, the problem occurs.  If I then detach the debugger, the Java process runs normally again.  Here is the code where the exception occurs:

```
protected void setDbConnection(DataSource dataSource)
        throws InterruptedException {
    boolean connected = false;
    while (!connected) {
        try {
            dbConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
            connected = true;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            int retryTime = 5000; // 5 seconds
            final String msg =
                    String.format("Unable to connect to %s.  Retrying in %s ms",
                                  dataSource, retryTime);
            logger.error(msg, e);
            Thread.sleep(retryTime);
        }
    }
    logConnectionDebugInfo();
}
```

Here is the debugging information available from the debugger.  I notice a `SQLState` of "08006", but haven't been able to find much useful information about it.  I welcome any ideas about this problem.  Mostly, I'd like to fix it, but I'd also like to hear what it is about debugging that might be causing it.  Could it be some threading issue?

[image]

Update 3/28/2018: I can debug using Eclipse's Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) debugger without seeing this problem.

Comment: Hi, could you please raise a ticket here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE

Comment: At this point, I'm not sure that it's IntelliJ's fault.  I will soon try with another debugger.  I also don't have an easy way of pruning the problem down into a small, repeatable test case.  However, if I get another debugger to work, I will file a bug report.

Comment: I can debug using Eclipse's  Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) debugger without seeing this problem.

Comment: After upgrading to IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.3, I no longer see this problem.

Comment: Same problem with Eclipse 4.7.3a, but only in one of my workspaces... probabily a configuration problem then

Answer (score 2):

I had exact same issue in my eclipse 2020-12. I removed all the breakpoints and it worked fine. Seems some breakpoints were slowing it down, then the existing connection got closed forcibly by the remote host once it time out.